# Can I use "in" before "the" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

> I will sit the way I want to!

Can I write by using a preposition *in* before *the* in above sentence?

> I will sit in the way I want to!

Which is grammatically right?

Comment: Not remotely an answer to your question, but in standard USAian idiom, it's: _"I'll sit however I want!"_ (Often followed by a mild expletive.)

Comment: Both are grammatical, but the first is more idiomatic. "Correct" and "incorrect" are not useful terms in regard to your choices here.

Comment: i'd like to know the difference since I can't see how "**sit in the way I want**" is correct here.

Answer (score 1):

> I will sit the way I want to!
>   I will sit in the way I want to!

These both sound like awkward phrasings.

> "I'll sit however I want!"

As the commenter above wrote, that looks correct.

Other slight variations which could be imagined, in a Dr. Suess book:

"I will sit the way I want to sit, and stand the way I want to stand, and everyone both left and right will think that it was grand."

or

"I will sit in the way that I want to sit, and write in the way that I want to write, and even if they do object I will not start a fight!"